# delegate property vs. protocol adoption

Tags: ios, swift, delegation

What is the purpose of setting view controllers's property `delegate` to `self` if I allready declared adoption of a specific protocol at the top of class declaration. I provided example:

```
class TabBarViewController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Is it necessary to explicitly write  `self.delegate = self` and why? I feel like repeating myself.

Answer (score 1):

Conforming protocol adoption is separate from assigning that *instance* of `TabBarViewController` as the delegate. Adopting the protocol tells the compiler that this *type* implements the methods specified by the protocol declaration. Assigning the delegate is a separate step that assigns the `self` reference as the delegate. Additionally, not all protocols are used for delegates.

If `UITabBarController` were required to implement `UITabBarControllerDelegate`, then you wouldn't need the `self.delegate = self` line because that would always be true, but many people do not subclass `UITabBarController` and set the delegate to their own object, like `MyTabBarControllerDelegate` which only implements `UITabBarControllerDelegate`. This is basically separating concerns so that code can be structured in more modular ways.

This case just looks a little odd because usually the delegate assignment is to a different class. For instance, assigning a view controller as a `UITableViewDelegate` of a `UITableView`. In that case, most people don't subclass `UITableView`, but instead add the `UITableViewDelegate` adoption to the view controller that contains the `UITableView`, but the delegate paradigm is flexible enough for you to choose where to put that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

UITabBarController does not conforms to UITabBarControllerDelegate by default as shown in [UITabBarController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/) unlike UITabBarDelegate for example, so yes, it is necessary to explicitly write `self.delegate = self` in order to make delegate methods get called. And don't feel like repeating yourself, just treat delegate object as custom controller object